# File upload validation get trigger on upload button click but not on Ok Button

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-validate

I am validating File uploader using Jquery Validation like this:

**HTML**

```
<form class="getintouch_form" name="Form_Career" action="" id="frm">
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="UploadResume" placeholder="Upload Resume">    
  <button class="submitbtn bluebutton" id="BtnSend" type="button">Send</button>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$.validator.addMethod(
  "UploadResume",
  function(value, element) {
    return /\.(doc|docx|pdf)$/i.test(value);
  },
  "Only docx,doc,pdf file formats allow"
);
$("#frm").validate({
  onfocusout: function(element) {
    $(element).valid();
  },
  rules: {
    UploadResume: {
      required: true,
      UploadResume: true
    }
  },

  messages: {
    UploadResume: {
      required: "Resume is mandatory field."
    }
  },
});
```

**Issue**
Validation gets fired immediately after I click Upload button and not after I click ok button after selecting file. I want to trigger validation only after I select the file. I've attached Codepen Link as well.[image]

CodePen : https://codepen.io/Ruhard/pen/RgPeQP

Comment: @Sparky - My validation works fine. Issue is validation gets trigger on Choose button not on ok button of file dialog box. check the image I've attached

Comment: Apparently this plugin fails to trigger validation when the file is selected.  Please consider filing a report to the developer on his GitHub page.  Meanwhile, Rory's answer is a perfectly acceptable workaround that leverages the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

To create the behaviour you require, you can call `valid()` on the form under the `change` event of the input, which is fired after a file is selected. Try this:

```
$('#fileInput').change(function() {
  $('#frm').valid();
});
```

Comment: I dont want to submit form on file upload change, As I have other fields on form as well. I just want to trigger validation on file upload dialog box

Comment: In that case call `valid()` on the form. I updated the answer

Comment: Can't I handle in JQuery Validation any how? Should I need to write extra Code?

Comment: Also, which Code We need to remove to stop this functionality?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer.  The plugin does not trigger validation when the file is selected, so creating an event handler to trigger validation on this event is perfectly acceptable, although I would attach `.valid()` to `$(this)` in order to only trigger validation on the file upload field instead of the entire form:  https://jsfiddle.net/t2yu4rm1/

Answer (score 0):

Please try simple jquery function for validation and file type check.
Here i mention new jquery code for the same.

```
 function FileUploadValidation(){
  var allowedFiles = [".doc", ".docx", ".pdf"];
        var fileUpload = $("#fileInput");
        var regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(" + allowedFiles.join('|') + ")$");
        if (!regex.test(fileUpload.val().toLowerCase())) {
            alert("Please upload files having extensions: <b>" + allowedFiles.join(', ') + "</b> only.");
            return false;
        }        
        return true;
}
$( "#BtnSend" ).click(function() {
        FileUploadValidation();
});
$('#fileInput').bind('change', function() {
       if(!FileUploadValidation())
          $('#fileInput').val();
});
```